# Objective C - Append ellipsis to a UILabel that is centrally aligned, but don't move text

Tags: objective-c, text, uilabel, text-alignment

I have a UILabel that is near 100% width. The text is centrally aligned.

I have some code to append or otherwise walkthrough the addition of ellipses.

However this causes an issue where the UILabel moves whilst the animation occurs.  This is because the text is centrally aligned.

I would like my code to add or otherwise update the ellipses but not "move" the UILabel.

I don't want to be adding another label if I can help it, but if thats the only solution then cool.

The code follows;

```
// This is a method inside a custom UILabel subclass
- (void)startProgressAnimationWithInterval:(NSTimeInterval)interval
{
    self.isAnimatingProgress = YES;

    NSString *singleDot = @".";
    NSString *doubleDot = @"..";
    NSString *tripleDot = @"...";

    if (![self.text hasSuffix:tripleDot]) {
        self.text = [self.text stringByAppendingString:tripleDot];
    }

    self.progressTimer = [NSTimer vic_scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:interval userInfo:nil action:^(NSTimer *timer, NSInteger repeatIndex) {
        if ([self.text hasSuffix:tripleDot]) {
            self.text = [self.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:tripleDot withString:singleDot];
        }
        else if ([self.text hasSuffix:doubleDot]) {
            self.text = [self.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:doubleDot withString:tripleDot];
        }
        else {
            self.text = [self.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:singleDot withString:doubleDot];
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways of tackling this. For example, rather than changing the text, set the text to include the ellipses, but then just set the font color of a variable number of dots of the ellipses to a clear color of the `attributedText` of the label:

```
- (void)handleTimer:(NSTimer *)timer {
    if (++self.dotsToShow >= 4) self.dotsToShow = 0;  // an integer state that rotates 0, 1, 2, 3 and then repeats

    NSInteger dotsToHide = 3 - self.dotsToShow;

    NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.label.text];
    if (dotsToHide > 0) {
        [string setAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor clearColor]} range:NSMakeRange(string.length - dotsToHide, dotsToHide)];
    }
    self.label.attributedText = string;
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a good solution over making a new label. I will try it !  My background cannot be trusted though; its not always like a solid color but i will try it

Comment: Yep, I set the ellipses to transparent, so whatever your background is, it will show through.